# how to use expandable TableView or accordion In Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift

i'm new to ios.
I want to make a navigation drawer with expandable menu how can I do.
I did navigation drawer but now want to add sub menu in the drawer but I didn't get how to do,Please help. thank you in advance.

here is my code for `DrawerViewController`

```
class LeftSideViewController: UIViewController ,UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate {

var menuItems:[String] = ["Main","Project","Client","User","About","Logout"]

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
{
    return menuItems.count;
}

public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{
    let mycell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "MenuItemCell", for: indexPath) as! MyCustomTableViewCell

    mycell.labelMenuItem.text = menuItems[indexPath.row]
    return mycell;
}

public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)
{
    switch (indexPath.row) {
    case 0:

        let centerViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "HomeViewController") as! HomeViewController

        let centerNavController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: centerViewController)

        let appDelegate:AppDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate

        appDelegate.centerContainer!.centerViewController = centerNavController
        appDelegate.centerContainer!.toggle(MMDrawerSide.left, animated: true, completion: nil)

        break;

    case 1:
        let aboutViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "AboutViewController") as! AboutViewController

        let aboutNavController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: aboutViewController)

        let appDelegate:AppDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate

        appDelegate.centerContainer!.centerViewController = aboutNavController

        appDelegate.centerContainer!.toggle(MMDrawerSide.left, animated: true, completion: nil)


        break;

    default:
        print("\(menuItems[indexPath.row]) is selected")
    }   
}
```

I have submenus for "Project" such as Add Project, Edit Project, delete Project.
when user click on Project i have show this submenus, like accordion,
and when user click on any submenu (add, edit or delete) it will open in new `ViewController`.

Answer (score -1):

```
@IBOutlet var tblViewMenu: UITableView!
var menuItems : NSMutableArray = ["dash","case","client"]
var subMenu : NSMutableArray = ["1","2"]
var menuToShow : NSMutableArray = []
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    menuToShow = menuItems
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return menuToShow.count;
}
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell : UITableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell")!
    let lblName : UILabel = cell.viewWithTag(1) as! UILabel
    lblName.text = menuToShow.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row) as? String
    return cell;
}
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true)
    menuToShow = subMenu
    tableView.reloadSections(NSIndexSet.init(index: 0), withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Fade)
}
```

Comment: Sorry but i am bit confuse. i assigned    this                                                            var subMenuItems :[String] = ["Add","Update","Delete"]
var menuToShow : [String] = menuItems                                                        in switch case because i have different submenu for each. but how can i append them?

Comment: what can i do to make them collapsible?

Comment: on click specific row at that time you assign subMenuItems to MenuTo show and reload sections with animation which i already mentioned.

Comment: it's little bit different from collapsible but i think it's best option compare to collapsible.

Comment: why you are using switch statement ,there is no need for that.only assign menu items to MenuTo Show in ViewDidLoad and after when Selection of row just assign submenu to menutoshow.

Comment: im doing like this is it right ?   `public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)
    {
        
        
        var subMenuItems :[String] = ["Add","Update","Delete"]
    
        var menuToShow : [String] = menuItems
        
        func deselectRow(at indexPath: IndexPath, animated: Bool){
            if(indexPath.row == 0){
                menuToShow = subMenuItems
            }
            
        }`

Comment: public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) { var subMenuItems :[String] = ["Add","Update","Delete"]  menuToShow = submenuItems

Comment: now Call [tableView deselectrowAtindexPath] to deselect existing selection in the didselectrow function.

Comment: and reload tableview section like this [self.tableView reloadSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:0] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade]; it's objc code you can find appropriate swift function for it

Comment: ya done.but its not working. still the same, submenu not added.

Comment: one more thing the condition if(indexPath.row == 0) is for to show different - 2 submenu option on click menu options

Comment: sorry but i didnt get what r u saying.

Comment: i update my answer ,you can check it and it's running well.

Comment: ok,so I did anything wrong? can you please tell me.
`public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath){
  var subMenuItems :[String] = ["Add","Update","Delete"]
 menuToShow = menuItems
 func deselectRow(at indexPath: IndexPath, animated: Bool){
            if(indexPath.row == 0){
                menuToShow = subMenuItems
            }           
        }        
        func reloadSections(_ sections: IndexSet, with animation: UITableViewRowAnimation){
        }
}`

Comment: Do it like this func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath){ var subMenuItems :[String] = ["Add","Update","Delete"] tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true){ if(indexPath.row == 0){ menuToShow = subMenuItems }  tableView.reloadSections(NSIndexSet.init(index: 0), withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Fade)}

Comment: now it's working.but the problem is  when I select menu it will show submenu only. the main menu hiding. is not showing main menu ones submenu select.

Comment: you need to call deselect and reload section function with current tableview  reference but here you doing implementation of these function which is not an correct approach

Comment: you can provide an back arrow button to go last menu section.

Comment: user your logical skills how can you achieve this otherwise i will help you